# error C3892: 'std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, constants

plz help me for this error and ... (visual studio 2010)

```
void file_remove(u32 id, int action) {
    file f;
    f.id = id;

    **file_set::iterator i = fs.find(f);**

    if(i == fs.end()) return;

    // move cursor away
    if(conf.expose.cursor == id) cursor_down();
    if(conf.expose.cursor == id) cursor_up();
    if(conf.expose.cursor == id) conf.expose.cursor = 0;


    if(action != 1 && i->size >= conf.files.incomp_min_size &&
        (u64)segment_summ(i->seg) * 100 / i->size >= conf.files.incomp_percent)
    {   action = 2;     }

    char n1[0x100];
    char n2[0x100];


    if(!i->deleted){
        cache_close(i->h);

        snprintf(n1, sizeof(n1), "%s/%s", conf.fnames.dir_temp, i->name.c_str());

        if(action == 0)
        {   // just close
        }
        else if(action == 1)
        {
            snprintf(n2, sizeof(n2), "%s/%s", conf.fnames.dir_ok, i->name.c_str());         seg(*i, conf.fnames.dir_temp, false);
        cache_move(n1, n2);
        }
        else if(action == 2)
        {
            snprintf(n2, sizeof(n2), "%s/%s", conf.fnames.dir_incomplete, i->name.c_str());
        seg(*i, conf.fnames.dir_incomplete, true, true);
        seg(*i, conf.fnames.dir_temp, false);
        cache_move(n1, n2);
        }
        else if(action == -1)
        {
            seg(*i, conf.fnames.dir_temp, false);
        cache_move(n1, ""); // unlink
        }
    } else {
        ffs_remove(i->size, i->tag);
        fs.erase(i);
        sort_files();
        return;
    }

    if(!i->tmp){
        ffs_remove(i->size, i->tag);
        fs.erase(i);
    } else {
        **i->deleted = true;**
    }
    sort_files();
}
```

compile it and error with this element : i->deleted = true; + view this result

> 1>main.cpp(478): error C3892:
>   'std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator<_Mytree,_Base>::operator ->' :
>   you cannot assign to a variable that is const 1>          with 1>
>   [ 1>
>   _Mytree=std::_Tree_val,std::allocator,false>>,
>   1>              _Base=std::_Iterator_base 1>          ]

http://up.vbiran.ir/images/w21nnbxc7tf5okzk0lr.png

http://up.vbiran.ir/images/x0coajrixr764g49ibeh.png

plz help me for resolve this error

Comment: Hello, your is completely unreadable as it is posted. Please edit your question, delete the whole block, then simply paste your code back, highlight it and click on the `{}` button.

Comment: The best way to get help is to post a minimal working example that we can copy/paste/compile to reproduce the error. See http://sscce.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is this line that is the problem

```
i->deleted = true;
```

In a `std::set` all the elements are const (because changing the value might invalidate the order of the set).